# How to user UserDefaults to Save Logged in state?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, userdefaults

i'm making introdution for my app, in swift 4 but i ran intro a problem. i have a introController and HomeController view,root view is introController so i want if user logged in to HomeController from introControll, then Whenever user open app, the first view appear is HomController, ( they don't need to login again ).

I think about store login state inside of userDefaults, i don't want my app use Navigation, any idea? please help

thanks in advance

Comment: You can just store a bool variable in userDefaults and each time they open the app, check to see if the variable is true. If its true, move user to the home controller

Answer (score 3):

When you make login save any bool value like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("1", forKey: "isLogin")
```

In appdelegate check login state like this:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isLogin") != nil{
            //Navigate to homeviewcontroller
 }else{
            //Navigate to rootviewcontroller
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but can you show some detail code in appdelegate ?

Comment: thats not a bool, your saving a string "1" with the key "isLogin"

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple

**You need to save state in UserDefaults when user successfully logged in like that: [Swift 3, 4]**

```
/// call if user logged in
func saveLoggedState() {

    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.set(true, forKey: "is_authenticated") // save true flag to UserDefaults
    def.synchronize()

}
```

**Then in AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions before return true**

```
let def = UserDefaults.standard
let is_authenticated = def.bool(forKey: "is_authenticated") // return false if not found or stored value

if is_authenticated {
    // user logged in
    let homeController = HomeController() // create instance of HomeController or from Storyboard

    window?.rootViewController = homeController // change rootViewController to HomeController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // show window
}
```

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions only gets called during initial launching of the app, so there won't be any user authentication unless they remove the app from the tray and then re-launch it.

Comment: Yeah I know, so questioner needs to call saveLoggedState one time when user logged in so next app run, it opens HomeController directly... I understood that his issue with next run

Comment: the original question just says he wants it to validate user when the user "opens the app". So could be just coming back from being inactive.

Comment: so, what's the problem? when app comes back from background, app will not calling didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and will back to last state of app before going to background so no need to handle authenticated state here... We just need to handle first run of app by implementing our login in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: welcome, please approve answer as accepted one if everything is ok